# Connection refused to WSL(Linux) Host

Tags: linux, wsl2

I'm trying to deploy XQuery code on the MarkLogic server installed on a Rocky Linux distribution (running within the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)).

I've encountered a problem while trying to deploy the code using the following Gradle command:

```
./gradlew -debug -b  deploy.gradle deploy -PmlHost="in-f6krxm3" -PdeployTestModule="false" -PreplicasCount=0 -PhostsInCluster=1 -PforestsPerHost=1
```

However, I'm getting the following exceptions, where it is not able to access the http://in-f6krxm3:8002 port of the server

```
Execution failed for task ':mlDeleteAllTasks'.
> I/O error on GET request for "http://in-f6krxm3:8002/manage/v2/tasks": Connect to in-f6krxm3:8002 [in-f6krxm3/192.168.1.7, in-f6krxm3/172.17.48.1,
 in-f6krxm3/172.23.144.1, in-f6krxm3/fe80:0:0:0:615:5c1:ea09:329a%12, in-f6krxm3/fe80:0:0:0:48c6:db8:775c:187e%46, in-f6krxm3/fe80:0:0:0:d61a:e56:5f
05:3c4d%27] failed: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to in-f6krxm3:8002 [in-f
6krxm3/192.168.1.7, in-f6krxm3/172.17.48.1, in-f6krxm3/172.23.144.1, in-f6krxm3/fe80:0:0:0:615:5c1:ea09:329a%12, in-f6krxm3/fe80:0:0:0:48c6:db8:775c:187e%46, in-f6krxm3/fe80:0:0:0:d61a:e56:5f05:3c4d%27] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

Also, when executing the command from within the Linux system in WSL2., the code was deployed successfully.

Could someone provide guidance on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: What's *in-f6krxm3*? Your Windows host name? Magic WSL bindings only work on *localhost*, *127.0.0.1* or *::1*.